# Clip and a transform:rotate(...)

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, clip

I have a rotated, absolute positioned div inside a container div.

I want to clip the rotated div so it fits inside the container. Can I do that?

EDIT: For those who have no idea about this, please see CSS3 `clip`. I could not get it to do this. (Chrome)

I tried `clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto)` which I believed should do the clipping for me.

Comment: Please...you've got to show at least some effort.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I have tried of course, but I do not know why it failed.

So can all of those downvoting this please tell how they fixed it? ;-)

Comment: Post the code from what you have tried

Comment: @Leo something like that demo - http://jsfiddle.net/oumwnvno/

Comment: Thanks @MaryMelody, yes. Just add `top:0; left:0;`there. Then you will see that it does not clip to inside the containing div.

Comment: @Leo just use `position: relative;` to containing div - http://jsfiddle.net/oumwnvno/3/

Comment: @Leo perfect clip demo - http://jsfiddle.net/oumwnvno/4/ :)

Comment: Thanks @MaryMelody, but that actually moves the read quadrant instead of clipping it. If you remove `position:relative`from the blue quadrant then the red square is in the position I want it to be - but then the read quadrant overflows the blue quadrant (which is exactly what I tried to ask about in my question).

Comment: @Leo could you please upload a screenshot or image that show what exactly you want to do? use that site and comment the url of image  - http://tinypic.com/

Comment: I took your fiddle instead, @MaryMelody, and added a little grey div above the blue quadrant. That hides the part of the red quadrant that stick up above the blue quadrant: http://jsfiddle.net/oumwnvno/5/

Comment: :-) - I think it is a bug in Chrome or maybe a vagueness in the specs. But maybe I am missing something so I thought it was better to ask here first to see if someone happened to know. (The down-voters makes asking such questions just a bit more troublesome. They down-votes many things they do not understand, unfortunately. And so those people that might know perhaps never sees the question. :-( )

Comment: @Leo I already gave you a +1 vote, so don't worry! and I don't think you can clip the corners of a div... sorry and if I'll find something out then I'll leave a comment for you... Good Luck! :) - http://jsfiddle.net/oumwnvno/8/

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. :-) -- The only thing I am worried about it that there might be someone here that knows if it is a bug or not, but does not look at this. I will wait until tomorrow until I report my problem as a bug. Then the Chrome developers have to find out if it is a bug or not... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the editing, @BoltClock. Sorry for spreading wrong info about `clip` and CSS3. :-( (Did I hear the Chrome devs thanking you too?)

Comment: To all down-voters: Which of you knew the solution? Could maybe those of you that knew the solution remove the down-votes? I mean you must know it is a real question? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, [`clip` isn't new to CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#clipping). In fact, [it's been *deprecated* in favor of an entire collection of new properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking/#clip-property).

Second, here's what the CSS2.1 spec says about `clip`:

> In CSS 2.1, the only valid `<shape>` value is: `rect(<top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left>)` where `<top>` and `<bottom>` specify offsets from the top border edge of the box, and `<right>`, and `<left>` specify offsets from the left border edge of the box. Authors should separate offset values with commas.

This means:

- `clip` works on the element itself. No other element is affected.
- `clip: auto`, or `clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto)` has no effect on an element because it's the same as not clipping the element at all. Any transforms that may be in effect are irrelevant because they actually transform the clipping region along with the rest of the element.

To clip an absolutely-positioned element to its containing block, use [`overflow: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) on the containing block instead. Ensure that you actually designate its containing block using `position: relative` or similar.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, very good! I was not really aware of that `clip` was depreceated. I saw that [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) mentioned it, but mentioned `clip-path` instead which is quite misleading. It just made me think about a change to syntax. (There seem to have been different ways to interpret `rect(auto, auto, auto, auto)`, but since `clip`is depreceated that is nothing to care about any more then.)

Comment: as IE still (10/2016) does not support clip-path so far, clip is still the right way to go. If you need non-rect shapes, you could go for SVG.

Comment: If you need to support IE, use clip or SVG. If IE doesn't already support clip-path, it never will. IE isn't getting any more new features. There is no point waiting.